# Continous notification after 2 minutes android

Tags: android, service, notifications

I want to show continuous notifications in my application.

Currently I am able to raise notification automatically after 4sec but what I want is it should continuously raise after specific time interval.

Following is my code.

my xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<Button android:id="@+id/notify"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Raise a notification"
  android:onClick="notifyMe"
  />
  <Button android:id="@+id/cancel"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Clear the notification"
  android:onClick="clearNotification"
  />
 </LinearLayout>
```

this is my activity file

```
package com.vimaltuts.android.notificationexample;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

      public class NotificationExampleActivity extends Activity {

  private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1987;
  private int count=0;
  private NotificationManager mgr=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mgr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
       public void run()
       {
           View v = new View(getApplicationContext());
           notifyMe(v);
       }},4000);
    }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public void notifyMe(View v) 
  {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat,"Status message!",System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this, NotificationMessage.class),0);
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "New Email","Unread Conversation", i);
    note.number=++count;
    note.vibrate=new long[] {500L, 200L, 200L, 500L};
    note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;      
    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
  }

  public void clearNotification(View v) {
    mgr.cancel(NOTIFY_ME_ID);
  }
}
```

Please tell me where should I need to have additional code if any?

Also is it possible with service..how?

---

i tried following code foe test purpose but it did't work...can anyone tell me where i goes wrong

following is my activity code

```
    Intent i= new Intent(NotificationExampleActivity.this,NotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(NotificationExampleActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.cancel(pi);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(alarmMgr.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),(10*1000), pi);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And following is my broadcast reciver

```
 Toast.makeText(context, "Repeating Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

i want to display msg="Repeating Alarm worked" after some time intervel

Answer (score 1):

Try using an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) along with the notification.

You can set a repeating alarm in your `Activity`. Then create a class that extends the `BroadcastReceiver`. Override the `onReceive` method where in you can write the code for your notification.

A tutorial on this is explained very well over [here](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html).